# Winter 18 Community - all custom components disappeared!

Tags: lightning-aura-components, customer-community, community-builder, lightning-community, winter18

On my sandbox I have winter 18 now.

I have played around to see all new community features, and suddenly I realize that the component list does not have any custom components:

[image]

**As you can see - no section Custom Components**

Also - my existing custom components (that where added before the Winter18 upgrade) exist in current pages, but when I click on any of them to see and edit their properties, I get the following error message:

> We had trouble processing the request. We've reported the problem to Customer Support with error ID: 972428812

[image]

Last thing - I have checked my production org, and over there I can see and manage my custom component:

[image]

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Wondering why my custom components work fine in Winter 18 dev org, component bundle versions ? debug mode On / Off  ?

Comment: version was old, but it should have been, anyway - now it works, I do not know what happened - maybe salesforce fixed it in the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now problem is solved - it works, I do not know what happened, I did not change anything, but I can see and use all my custom components in my communities.

Maybe Salesforce fixed it in the background or something...

Comment: Lucky you. I am having this come and gone randomly.